# multiple replacements on a single variable

Tags: macos, bash

For the following variable:

`var="/path/to/my/document-001_extra.txt"`

i need only the parts between the `/` [slash] and the `_` [underscore].
Also, the `-` [dash] needs to be stripped.

In other words: `document 001`

This is what I have so far:

`var="${var##*/}"`

`var="${var%_*}"`

`var="${var/-/ }"`

which works fine, but I'm looking for a more compact substitution pattern that would spare me the triple `var=...`

Use of sed, awk, cut, etc. would perhaps make more sense for this, but I'm looking for a pure bash solution.

Needs to work under GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing your question to talk about patterns instead of regular expressions, I'll now show you how to *actually* use regular expressions in `bash` :)

```
[[ $var =~ ^.*/(.*)-(.*)_ ]] && var="${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:2}"
```

Parameter expansions like you were using previously unfortunately cannot be nested in `bash` (unless you use ill-advised `eval` hacks, and even then it will be less clear than the line above).

The `=~` operator performs a match between the string on the left and the regular expression on the right. Parentheses in the regular expression define match groups. If a match is successful, the exit status of `[[ ... ]]` is zero, and so the code following the `&&` is executed. (Reminder: don't confuse the "0=success, non-zero=failure" convention of process exit statuses with the common Boolean convention of "0=false, 1=true".)

`BASH_REMATCH` is an array parameter that `bash` sets following a successful regular-expression match. The first element of the array contains the full text matched by the regular expression; each of the following elements contains the contents of the corresponding capture group.

The `${foo[@]:x:y}` parameter expansion produces `y` elements of the array, starting with index `x`. In this case, it's just a short way of writing `${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`. (Also, while `var=${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1:2}` would have worked as well, I tend to use `@` anyway to reinforce the fact that you almost always  want to use `@` instead of `*` in other contexts.)

Comment: it prints nothing on my prompt.

Comment: It sets var. It doesn't output anything.

Comment: Add `echo` to print. Thanks for editing my question. Could you explain what's going on, though? Especially the BASH_REMATCH part.

Comment: Awsome pedagogical step by step explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following should work correctly. Though the second is sensitive to misplaced characters (if you have a `/` or `-` after the last `_` it will fail).

```
var=$(IFS=_ read s _ <<<"$var"; IFS=-; echo ${s##*/})

var=$(IFS=/-_; a=($var); echo "${a[@]:${#a[@]} - 3:2}")
```