# Matching multiple Uppercases in string with patterns and $BASH_REMATCH

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to return every uppercase letter in a user-entered string. All characters are in UTF-8 and none are invisible. For example let's say that the user enters "Hello World", Bash should return H and W:

```
str="Hello World"; [[ "$str" =~ [A-Z] ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[@]}
```

I've tried all sorts of complicated patterns which I'm sparing you — none of them worked.

The most simple pattern for the job I can think of only returns the first match, H. Strangely it will match both H and W on http://www.regexr.com/.

Who could help me with the right pattern to match all uppercases in any string, that would be sort of emulating `grep -o`?

(GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13))

(Edited to replace all occurrences of ‘regular expression’ or ‘regex’ with ‘pattern’ after rereading the answer @chepner posted to one of my previous questions: [multiple replacements on a single variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913456/multiple-replacements-on-a-single-variable))

Comment: What's wrong with `echo "Hello World" | grep -o '[A-Z]'` ?

Comment: Just trying to understand pure Bash better. I'd be thankful for an explanation concerning the use of $BASH_REMATCH in my question — regardless whether it is possible or not. I would accept such an answer, if only for its pedagogical value.

Comment: The problem isn't with the regular expression itself, but `bash`'s regular expression engine. It doesn't support the `g` flag you used at www.regexr.com to make multiple matches.

Comment: Also, here you really *are* using regular expressions with the `=~` operator, not patterns :)

Answer (score 3):

With bash builtins:

```
str="Hello World"
for ((i=0;i<${#str};i++)); do [[ ${str:$i:1} =~ [[:upper:]] ]] && echo ${str:$i:1}; done
```

Output:

```
H
W
```

Comment: Nice use of brace expansion. I'd vote this up if I had privileges. Is there a way to avoid the for loop and use $BASH_REMATCH instead?

Comment: Brace expansion is the expansion of something like `{1..3}` to `1 2 3`. This is an example of the substring expansion operator for parameter expansions.